# How can I know **which** of my flags were marked as invalid?

Tags: support, flags

Is there a way to know **which** of my flags were marked as invalid?

Comment: +1 join the club. I know for sure When i flag this as duplicate it is going to be marked as valid :P . **Duplicate 1** [Help me find the bad flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86981/help-me-find-the-bad-flag) **Duplicate 2** [How do I know if my flag on a question was a worthy one?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87751/how-do-i-know-if-my-flag-on-a-question-was-a-worthy-one) I know it is going to be closed as duplicate as **The powers that Be** do not want to provide this feature. why? God only knows.

Comment: @AdityaGameProgrammer I tried to find if it was asked but couldn't :/

Comment: That's understandable.you can imagine when i tried searching for [Do Dismissed flags cost same amount as before the 500 mark?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88286/do-dismissed-flags-cost-same-amount-as-before-the-500-mark) the op of the similar post had to post a link to his as it was hard to search.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally speaking, when a moderator takes an action on a post, the flag is dismissed as "valid". So theoretically if you don't see this:

[image]

then it could have been dismissed as "invalid".

However, there have been some interesting flagging issues of late. I think we should have a clear "Flag dismissed as ___" comment on each flag. How can we find out whether we've been flagging appropriately if there's no way to tell?

Comment: so invalid flags won't appear?

Comment: @Oscar: They will still appear, but the action taken (the part in the red rectangle) will be absent because no action was taken.

Comment: Oh, I see! I think that will help me a little more, although I agree with you about finding out wheter we've been flagging appropiately ;)

Comment: I've had several flags where no action was taken, but the flag was not marked invalid either... But in general, your answer is correct.