# Please add an indication of which of my flags were dismissed as valid/invalid

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-history

First of all, I'm *AWARE* of this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89186/how-can-i-know-which-of-my-flags-were-marked-as-invalid) but its answer doesn't answer mine.

In the mentioned question it states that in order to check if a flag is valid, the question has probably been locked, deleted, migrated, etc.

But it also states:

> However, there have been some
>   interesting flagging issues of late. I
>   think **we should have a clear "Flag dismissed as _"** comment on each flag.

In my flagging history I see this:

[image: exact duplicate flags]

I'm sure that both flags can't be invalid. Because I have 2 invalid flags and I know one invalid flag which isn't one of the 2 in the picture. So there is a possibility that one of 2 flags is invalid. **How can I tell which one?**

From all my flags I don't really know exactly which ones were invalid and I have no idea at all what was disputed. It is hard to keep track of it.

I think a feature like this can help us to understand how to flag more properly.

Comment: wait until you have no more flags waiting to be processed. Then you will be enlightened.

Comment: @Kate Gregory all my flags are processed

Comment: Any flag that says "exact duplicate" when it *isn't* an **exact duplicate** was probably marked invalid.  [You should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)  Its normally only when that duplication indicates some other issue that they get acted upon.  For example, a noob that asks the same question twice from two different accounts.

Comment: Also, ***irony!***

Comment: @Won't As I say in my question, I'm sure that both the 2 flags can't be invalid. So only one(?) of them is, which one? You are not answering my question. And I don't see were the irony is, as my question is not duplicate at all. Checking for closed/deleted/migrated is a way to find valid flags, but sometimes a post wasn't closed/deleted/migrated and it's invalid, how I can find which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag page has changed. 2011-06-28 [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[image: flag status]

Now we can clearly see each flag and it tells:

- Valid
- Disputed
- Invalid (in red)

Note: older flags were not recorded valid/invalid/disputed