# May I have a list of just my declined flags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, flag-history

There is a helpful summary of one's flags just to the right of one's flagging summary:

```
Your flagging history

1024 moderator attention flags
1023 deemed helpful
   1 declined
 512 disputed

128 posts marked spam
 64 deemed helpful

 32 posts marked offensive

4096 comments flagged
  32 deemed helpful
  32 declined
```

I'd really like each of the "declined" and "disputed" to be hyperlinked to a filtered list of exactly the flags I cast that our moderators didn't find helpful, so that I can more readily learn from my mistakes.

[The existing interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96699/157556) means I've got skim through the list and look for the lines that *don't* say "helpful" among 14 pages of flags. (Your pages may vary.)

Comment: As I understood, 'disputed' has nothing to do with the moderators, it means somebody else (okay, might have been a mod) thought otherwise. Every time you vote 'invalid flag', that goes into your history as disputed, as in the other's.

Comment: @DanielFischer Disputed flags still go to the moderators, although with a note that they were deemed invalid. When they show up as merely disputed in your flagging history, they were marked helpful. Flags that are disputed and then declined show the reason, like so: `disputed - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`.

Comment: @Daniel: I _think_ that the _disputed_ entry also includes the flags that _I_ disputed in addition to my flags that _others_ disputed. It'd be nice to know which ones are which.

Comment: Understandable. So far I have only the first kind, I'm still new and a little shy with flagging, but when that changes, I'd sure also like to know which are which.

Comment: Mods can also clear a spam/offensive flag as disputed if it was once cleared as helpful but was manually cleared from the post.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, yes you can effective immediately. Oded implemented flag history filtering.  Along the side bar, you are now able to select your declined flags and see a list of only those flags.