# Where can I find the flagging summary on my profile?

Tags: support, flags, profile-page, flag-history

I cannot find the flagging summary on my user profile.

I have seen many questions about flagging system: [May I have a list of just my declined flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119816/may-i-have-a-list-of-just-my-declined-flags), [What does empty "Flagging Summary" page mean when "helpful flags" is "1"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122424/what-does-empty-flagging-summary-page-mean-when-helpful-flags-is-1), [What does the helpful flag mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128178/what-does-the-helpful-flag-mean), etc.

I know the results of my flags are not of my business and moderators are responsible for the follow up, but I would like to see the summary as there are other things involved, such as `Deputy` and `Marshal` badges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your [profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/profile-page/info), below the profile views

> [image: flag count]

there is the helpful flag count. Click on the number to go to your flagging history.

Comment: Dear God. There is a small `more info` next to my name to display more details about my profile. I haven't seen it before. Many thanks.

Comment: Ah, I thought the default was the more comprehensive view with the "less info" link.

Comment: Why is this marked as correct answer? It should have been @Glorfindel answer that should be marked as correct answer. At least in my case for blender.stackexchange.com. Is each community's profile/activity page differently structured?

Answer (score 6):

The information has been moved. It's now easiest to just click on your user widget in the navigation bar; wherever you may be on the site, this will open your profile page with the 'Activity' tab already selected (unlike other users' profile pages which open on the 'Profile' tab by default). The number of helpful flags is in the Impact widget on the right side, and it's (still) a link to your flagging summary.

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to view your flagging summary throughout the Stack Exchange network, you can install the [Global Flagging Summary userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/7173/34061). It will add a Flags tab to your network profile:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323066/312043), there is a new feature added recently.

By using the URL [`<sitename>/users/flag-summary/current`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current), you can directly navigate to your flag summary page.