# How can I determine if a moderator has reviewed something I flagged

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

I was a bit frustrated after having two questions closed on SO one was claimed to be too general one was too specific.  Fortunately I got what I needed/ was hoping to get from the questions but after the second was closed I flagged it and asked for a moderator to review the second closing.  The closing voters said I should move the question to code review which I did not know about until that comment but I was struggling to see how my question was different from many of the other questions on the site.

Anyway- I flagged the one question and have been anxiously checking my messages to see what came of moderator review but nothing has happened as of yet.

Here is the question [Question Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862313/better-way-to-implement-a-machine-learning-algorithm-in-python)

Just to be clear - I am trying to find out how I will learn of the result of the moderator review of my flag

Comment: On your profile page, there's a helpful flag count (visible only to you [and devs, probably also mods]). That's a link to your flagging history page. There you can see the status of your flag.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the information.

Comment: Curious why your meta account is not linked with your SO account?  It's not disallowed, but are you possibly question banned?

Comment: @casperOne no for some reason when I log into the meta account it links to another gmail account I need to spend some time figuring out how to combine my identities

Comment: related / duplicate: [where can I find the flagging summary on my profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141040/where-can-i-find-the-flagging-summary-on-my-profile)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your profile, click on the number next to "helpful flags" and you will get a list of your flags. If a moderator reviewed it, there will be a "helpful" or "declined" or something else next to the flag you are looking for.

[image]

You can visit your flagging summary through that link directly:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/199564

where the last number is your User Account number.