# Is there a way to know if a moderator has addressed a flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine if a moderator has reviewed something I flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151611/how-can-i-determine-if-a-moderator-has-reviewed-something-i-flagged)

Sorry if this is a duplicate.  I recently had an answer migrated to SuperUser.  I disagreed with the migration so I flagged the post for moderator attention as suggested in my previous question on meta.

I'm watching the post to see if it gets moved back to Stack Overflow (so I can edit my answer as I realized there's a problem with it).  However, in the event that a moderator doesn't agree with my flag and thinks that SuperUser is the place where that post belongs, I would like to know.  That way, I'll know that I need to get an account on SuperUser in order to correct my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to your Flag Summary page and keep track of your flags and their progress. For you on Stack Overflow this will most likely be http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/748858

Alternatively you can access it by clicking on the number of helpful flags within your profile.

> [image]