# Allow me to hide the "what are flags?" banner please!

Tags: feature-request, design, flags, profile-page

Recently, this text popped up on my flags-history page:

> Flagging is a way to bring inappropriate content or behavior to the attention of the community. See: What is flagging? These are the flags that you have raised, along with their current status. You can filter this list using the links in the sidebar.

[image]

Can we please have a way to dismiss that banner? It sticks around even when I move to the subsequent pages of flags. I really think we could fit some more flags in that place instead, and that banner even hurts a bit because of the [widow](https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-2/text-typography/rags-widows-orphans) (or orphan, since definitions are inconsistent AFAIK)

If I want to check on my last 3-4 flags, not needing to scroll would help me a bit, and a lot of us who check that page periodically already know what flags are and have raised a decent number of them so far, so we don't particularly need that link (and we know where to find it if we do need it).

I'm obviously not suggesting that this banner should be removed, since it's understandable that users who just got to 15 rep would discover that link on their profiles (in which case the system should give them some information), but I would either like a way to close it such that it doesn't show up again, or a system which automatically hides it for people with more than a certain number of helpful flags (50-ish?). If there're a couple of recent declined flags, it could pop up again, the way a warning appears in the flagging dialog.

Comment: **YES**! I understand how flags work and I do *not* need a reminder every time I see my flagging history.

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [Allow dismissing the “Flagging is a way to …” text on the flag summary page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380413/4642212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I added that because there was previously [no explanation of that page's purpose anywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288009/add-a-link-to-the-relevant-meta-post-in-the-flag-ban-notice/323066#323066), and I wanted to be able to [send folks there more readily](/users/flag-summary/current) without confusing them. There's a similar explanation for each of the status filters available on the right.

While I sympathize with not wanting to see unnecessary noise, it hardly takes up that much room. You're already using a userscript on that page... If it bothers you, I recommend adding

```
$("#mainbar>div:first:not(.flagged-post)").remove();
```

...to your script; this will strip the explanations from the page and leave you with the bare list of flags you had before.

Comment: If only we had [some kind of help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to explain that page's purpose. *"You can view the outcome of your past flags at any time by clicking on "helpful flags" in your profile. "*

Comment: I'm afraid that's not much of an explanation, @Stijn; folks would find their way there and still have no idea what to make of "declined", "disputed", "aged", etc. My hope is that putting that information right where it's needed will help alleviate that confusion.

Comment: _"it hardly takes up that much room"_ The amount of room it occupies is pretty much irrelevant. It's the nagging every. single. time. you. visit. the. page. It'a trivial to add a dismiss feature to it. As it is now, it's just bad UX.

Comment: For those using CSS-based user scripts, `#mainbar>div:first-child { display: none; }` is fine for this (until the markup changes...)

Comment: Caveat: if anyone uses that *and* manages to get flag-banned, it's gonna hide the first flag, @TylerH (the filter explanation is hidden in lieu of a larger banner explaining the ban at the top of the page in the default view). Hence the `not(.flagged-post)` pseudo-class in my expression.

Comment: @Shog9 But who would ever get flag banned?! \*hides in a corner...* :-)

Comment: It's not a terribly big concern, but... The way failure exhibits itself if it does happen ain't great either; ideally, err on the side of *not* hiding vs. hiding the wrong thing.