# Could you add "flags declined during the past 7 days" link in the help page?

Tags: feature-request, help-center, declined-flags, flag-history

As per [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323066/312043), we can use `/current` instead of `<userid>` in the flag summary URL.

In the [What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/declined-flags) help page, under the "**What happens if too many of my flags are declined?**" section the description as:

> If at least a quarter of 10 or more flags were declined during the past 7 days, you will be temporarily banned from raising new flags.

Currently we can able to link the URL to the flags were declined during the past 7 days as `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current?showDeclined=true`

Could you please add the declined flags link to the description, so the expected description with link as:

> If at least a quarter of 10 or more flags were [declined during the past 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current?showDeclined=true), you will be temporarily banned from raising new flags.

Comment: Note that *if you're banned*, a link to that filter appears in a banner at the top of the flag summary page, as well as in the sidebar.