# Where can I check my flags?

Tags: support, flags

I can't find where to find the flags raised by me.

I saw this link [Where can I find the flagging summary on my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141040/where-can-i-find-the-flagging-summary-on-my-profile)

But there is no flags count below my profile views.

Where can I check my flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you linked might use an update indeed. It's not exactly on your "profile" view anymore but on your activity page:

> [image: OP's activity page]

You can click it and access the flagging summary. I can't click the above because it's yours and not mine, but here's a snippet of what it should look like (from my own flagging page on SFF):

> [image: My flagging profile]

Answer (score 2):

In the ["Activity"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) tab - under the "IMPACT" section, you can see the number of links you have raised. Click on the link it will redirect to the flag-summary page:

> [image]